# How to draw a line or a curve in an image, interpolating some pixels?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, imshow

Let's suppose I have a 10x10 matrix (**img**). All elements are zero, except the point (0,0) and the point (9,9) equal to 0.5.

If I display such a matrix by means this code

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest')
```

then I see a black background and two gray pixels (in the left upper position and in the right-bottom one).

Now I would display the line joining these two points. So, in this case, I would that all pixels on the diagonal of the matrix are displayed as gray pixels.

Note that I need to a general case: so I would draw a line or a curve linking points in any positions (not only in this simple situation).

Comment: [matplotlib.pyplot.plot()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot)

Comment: I need to plot on the image.

Comment: Two concepts: the first one is that I don't know how to match the reference system between image and plot. The second one is that the interpolation can be, for example, an ellipse. So can I do that?

Comment: In your case it would be a field of 10x10 pixels where you can plot a line between any two of them. And to interpolate between two points is not possible anyway.